# Why doesn't my Launch Screen Image appear?

Tags: ios, xcode, screen, landscape, launch

Working in Xcode 5 I placed two images in the launch screen section. One for 640x960, as directed for the 3.5inch, And the other for 640x1136 for the 4 inch screen. No errors appear when I run the program, but upon startup it's still just a black screen before loading the program. What would be the reasoning for this?

Does it matter that the app is landscape only while the launch screen is for portrait?

Because the app while loading still comes up portrait for a few seconds before switching to landscape and then starting the app.

Any fixes?

**Edit:** I tried it on a portrait app, and it comes out fine, so it just doesn't work on landscape apps, which I don't have an option for since i have IOS 7.0 or later.

Answer (score 0):

If your app supports landscape orientations by default, you should include landscape launch images. Just add the appropriate images for each size and resolution to your launch image assets. Portrait launch images will not show up when starting the app in landscape orientations.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the files into your project with the correct names.
Like this:

- "Default-Landscape~ipad.png" (1024 x 768 px)
- "Default-Landscape~ipad@2x.png" (2048 × 1536 px)
- "Default-568h@2x.png" (640 × 1136 px)
- "Default-568h@3x.png" (1242 × 2208 px)
- "Default@2x.png" (640 × 960 px)

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer:**
Check if image you are using is in `.png` format. If not then you should convert it into, then it will start getting displayed inside your `LaunchScreen`.

**Detail:**

I have just figured out why.

I implemented LaunchScreen in an old project, added an `ImageView` in which I set an Image, but that was not displaying. I checked several things like:

- My auto layout setting
- If my launch screen se selected in project setting
- If I have selected right `.xib` or storyboard file

All was right still I was not being the image. Though `LaunchScreen` was loading fine(I made sure of that by changing background colour of `LaunchScreen` `View`).

So finally I figured that the problem might be with `image` an that was the case.

My `image`, which i used inside `LaunchScreen` `imageView` was in JPG format. An iOS devices aren't really friendly with `.JPG` format. So I changed the image to `.png` and not it load fine.